# Java app slower due to web start

Tags: java, java-web-start

I'm trying to deploy my Java application using Java Web Start, but I've come across a problem. When running the application through my IDE (Netbeans) it's lightning fast; everything happens within seconds. However if it's launched with Web Start it's excruciatingly slow.

Any ideas why?

I'm self-signing everything and using full permissions in the JNLP.

Comment: Different JVMs for the two scenarios?

Comment: What in particular is slow about the application?  Launching it?  Stuff that happens after launching it?  UI rendering?  Mouse is laggy?  Menus open up slowly?

Comment: @Mike- He clearly states that launching is slow.

Comment: @DMan-  He clearly does not state this.  He says when it's launched with web start "it's" slow, "it's" being undefined.

Comment: @Ryan- I'm not sure what you're saying. Mike Clark asked what was slow about the application. Dennis states "it's [slow when] launched with Web Start". "It's" is obviously the Java application.

Comment: @DMan It is not 100% obvious to me what Dennis means.  He used ambiguous phrasing, saying "it" and "everything" instead of specifying what *exactly* is slow.  Upon reflection, I think it is *likely* that he is talking about the speed of the launch, but it is not absolutely clear.  In addition, the title of the question makes it sound like the entire application is slower due to JWS, not just the launch.  And so I feel my request for clarification is a reasonable and valid one.

Comment: @Mike- I don't understand your ambiguity. Maybe it's just me, but I think it's really clear and obvious. `When running the application through my IDE (Netbeans) it's lightning fast; everything happens within seconds. However if [the application] launched with Web Start it's excruciatingly slow.` When he uses 'However if it's', it connects to the previous sentence, where he mentions 'the application'. Thus, he is asking why launching a Java application through Web Start is slower than locally with Netbeans.

Comment: My apologies for the unclear/bad phrasing. I was actually talking about the application itself, not the launch. Everything connected to external JARs was slow, i.e. creating graphs using jfreechart, looking up file info using a POSIX library, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java Web Start applications will always launch more slowly than launching directly via the `java` executable.  This is because Java Web Start is doing so much more than a standard `java` launch:

1. JWS accesses the network to download the JNLP (and possibly JARs, and other resources)
2. JWS is checking its local cache of JARs to see if it can skip downloading the JARs
3. JWS is potentially downloading the jars via HTTP, if the cache is empty or out of date
4. **JWS is checking the validity of the cryptographically strong signatures of every single jar**

I think most of this is an unavoidable cost for the added power of being able to launch your application via a web browser and update your application virtually "for free."

---

Another possibility: Is your application running with a different VM when you launch via webstart vs. when you launch with NetBeans? You can try printing:

```
System.getProperty("java.home")
```

to find out what VM is running the currently executing process.

If it's the same VM, you might also try **diffing** the Java system properties between the two scenarios.  Try printing out all System properties:

```
System.getProperties().store(System.out, "");
```

---

**[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)** can be used to help diagnose Java Web Start network issues.

---

Sometimes the [Java Console](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/deployment/deployment-guide/console.html) and Java Web Start Logging can be useful in diagnosing certain JWS problems.  You can enable these features through the [Java Control Panel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/deployment/deployment-guide/jcp.html):

[image]

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you for the comprehensive answer. By enabling tracing I was able to see that all the external JARs get downloaded when they are needed which caused the slow downs. My solution is to create a single JAR which works!

Answer (score 1):

You can enable full logging in the Java Console and see all the things that Java Web Start is printing of debug information.  You can then see where the pauses happen, which may give you an indication of the problem.

My initial guess would be that you have DNS issues, especially if the pauses are very close to a multiplum of 30 seconds.